# Delete single item from SharePoint 2013 Calendar recurrance event

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

We have SharePoint 2013 calendar, which handle booking of resources. Calendar was migrated from SharePoint 2010 with backward compatibility. It was working fine for around 7 months after migration.

Recently we found that there is one issue when deleting single item from recurrence event. It throws an error: "*Sorry, something went wrong, An unexpected error has occurred.*"

However, you can delete whole recurrence event successfully, but not single item in that recurrence event.

For all other case it works fine with CRUD operations.

There is no direct access to SharePoint logs, and therefore we still need to investigate using logs.

**Question:** if anyone comes across having similar error or have any suggestions?

**Update 1 (Server Log):**

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMap.GetColumnNumber(String strFieldName, Boolean bThrow) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.GetRawValue(String fieldname, Int32 iIndex, Boolean bThrow) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetValue(SPField fld, Int32 columnNumber, Boolean bRaw, Boolean bThrowException) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetValue(String strName, Boolean bThrowIfValueMissing, Boolean bThrowIfFieldMissing) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.RecurrenceField.SetExceptionsFields(Boolean bDeleteInstance) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeleteItemButton.DeleteFromRecurrenceSeries() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeleteItemButton.DeleteItem() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPLinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: can you check sharepoint logs for the error?

Comment: SharePoint servers are managed from other provider and that's why we don't have direct access to it, And I wanted to avoid time consuming ticket response process :) However ,if nothing works, there is no other option then asking to look at SharePoint logs.

Comment: ok. that means you dont have server access and you cant run powershell also. difficult to trace than. anyways do you have any event recievers attached to that list by any chance?

Comment: Yes, that's correct! I don't have server access and also can't run powershell. There is no event receiver attached to the list.

Comment: What irritates me is, why everything in calender is working except deletion of single item in recurrence event.

Comment: that happens..some times item gets corrupted

Comment: I agree, but it also have same behavior for new items :/

Comment: Please post your Update 2 as an answer instead of an edit to your post so that you can resolve the question and help future readers

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2 (Resolution)**: One lookup column was creating that issue. After deleting lookup column issue was resolved.